# jQuery slideshow - Images after the first one are not showing up

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an image slideshow. I have managed to develop the following code so far.  The problem is the following code displays the first image only. After the page loading is complete, the first image shows up perfectly from left and fades away after few seconds and then rest of the images just do not show up.

Could you please tell me how to show the rest of the images one after another?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $(".slider img").each(function() { 
            $(this).show("slide",{direction:'right'},1000);
            $(this).delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},1000);  
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="slider">
    <img src="slideshow/1.jpg"  />
    <img src="slideshow/2.jpg"  />
    <img src="slideshow/4.jpg"  />
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
 .slider{
  width: 980px;
  height:362px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-image:url(slideshow/ajax-loader.gif);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;

 }
.slider img {
 display:none;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Your code should move all the images simultaneously. Do you have any CSS involved here?

Comment: yes, I am going to add the css with my question here. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for:-

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJE9s/)

```
   $(function () {
    var imgArr = $('img').get(); // get the images in an array
    slide(); // invoke slide initially

    function slide() {

        var img = imgArr.shift(); //get the first image from the array
        imgArr.push(img); //push it back to the array for the cycle to happen
        $(img).show('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 1000, function () { //give image slide in in the call back of show
            $(this).delay(500).hide("slide", {
                direction: 'left'
            }, 1000, function () { // in the call back of hide call slide again.
                window.setTimeout(slide, 10);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) this is exactly what I was looking for. :) Would you mind if I ask you another question? When the current image fades away and the next image shows up in between this time time I can see a blank page(or ajax loading) for a while. How can I make the current image fades away and next image shows up simultaneously ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you're trying to show the images in sequence. There are a few ways you could do that. Here's one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var images = $('.slider img').hide();
    var current = 1;

    setInterval(function() {
       images.eq(current).hide("slide", {direction:'left'}, 1000);
       current = (current + 1) % images.length;
       images.eq(current).show("slide", {direction:'right'}, 1000);
    }, 5500);

    images.first().show();
});
```